# How to find the Analytics Label field from FCM in GA4 (GBQ tables)

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

We are creating push notifications campaigns with Firebase Cloud Messaging. When you create a campaign, you have an analytics label field, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve this data in GA4 (GBQ)? I can retrieve this data from the FCM API, but I want to know if I can find this field in GA4 in any particular way in GBQ.

I've read this FCM documentation about analytic labels but there is no clue about this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this label is located inside the event_params.key as 'label'. You can select the event_name as 'notification_open' and then the event_params.key to retrieve the opens for a specific label.

Here is the generic code to find this data:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
  `your-table`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS param 
WHERE
  session_date = '2023-09-25' -- update to your desired start and end date
  AND param.value.string_value="add here your analytics label"
  and event_name = 'add here your own FB event'
```